# Change active line color in Dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver

Is there any way to change the active line in Dreamweaver to something? Like yellow such as most text editors support. I've searched the preferences and don't seem to see it. Would make it much easier to see which line I'm currently on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dreamweaver CS4, you can click on the line number to the left of the text and it will highlight the line. As soon as press an up or down arrow key or click on another part of the text, the highlight goes away.  I think that's about as close as you're going to get. They probably don't offer a constant highlight because it would interfere with the code coloring.